# C/C++ Pointer to a POD struct also points to the 1st struct member

Tags: c++, c, pointers, struct

Can I assume that a C/C++ struct pointer will always point to the first member?

Example 1:

```
typedef struct {
 unsigned char  array_a[2];
 unsigned char  array_b[5];
}test;
//..
test var;
//..
```

In the above example will &var always point to array_a?
Also in the above example is it possible to cast the pointer
to an unsigned char pointer and access each byte separately?

Example 2:

```
function((unsigned char *)&var,sizeof(test));
//...
//...
void function(unsigned char *array, int len){
 int i;
 for( i=0; i<len; i++){
    array[i]++;
 }
}
```

Will that work correctly?

Note: I know that chars are byte aligned in a struct therefore I assume the size of the above struct is 7 bytes.

Comment: I think at least for [tag:c++] you can't rely on this.

Comment: Chars are by default not byte aligned in a `struct` - if you haven't instructed your compiler to do otherwise, it probably aligns to wordsize.

Comment: First member yes, anything else no.

Comment: You know what assume is an acronym for? Yes it will point to the first member. Don't assume what the first member is though. :(

Comment: Why do you need such function?

Comment: Which language are you asking about? C and C++ are different languages and (in this case) the answer is quite different for each·

Comment: @MikeSeymour I imagine that since I am talking about plain old data it is the same for C as for C++. But I am mainly interested in C++.

Comment: @atkarapa: You don't restrict the question to POD types, except in the subquestions about that specific example. You ask "Can I assume that a C/C++ struct pointer will always point to the first member?", the answer to which depends on the language. If you want to know about two different languages, you should ask two questions.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I did know there was such a difference before. I changed the question

Comment: @AlexanderGessler Based on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment GCC, Borland, VC++ do align by default by 1 byte for `char` types. I do not know what the rest of the compilers do.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Based on the answer given below for POD structs the pointer points to the 1st member even for C++

Comment: @atkarapa Well of course it does, where else would it point to? The point I was making was if you insert a new first member and you've made use of this to avoid directly referencing the first member, you will have  problems...

Comment: @TonyHopkinson I didn't know for sure that the reason I ask. The struct will never change, if the 1st member changes I will want to point to the new 1st member. But, it will never change.

Comment: Never, ooh bad word. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the C99 standard section 6.7.2.1 bullet point 13:

> Within a structure object, the non-bit-field members and the units in
>   which bit-fields reside have addresses that increase in the order in
>   which they are declared. A pointer to a structure object, suitably
>   converted, points to its initial member (or if that member is a
>   bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides), and vice versa.
>   There may be unnamed padding within a structure object, but not at its
>   beginning.

The answer to your question is therefore yes.

[Reference](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf) (see page 103)

Comment: "The answer to your question is therefore yes"... for C.

Answer (score 10):

For C structs, yes, you can rely on it. This is how almost all "object orientated"-style APIs work in C (such as GObject and GTK).

For C++, you can rely on it only for "plain old data" (POD) types, which are guaranteed to be laid out in memory the same way as C structs. Exactly what constitutes a POD type is a little complicated and has changed between C++03 and C++11, but the crux of it is that if your type has any virtual functions then it's not a POD.

(In C++11 you can use `std::is_pod` to test at compile-time whether a struct is a POD type.)

EDIT: This tells you what constitutes a POD type in C++: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/PODType

EDIT2: Actually, in C++11, it doesn't need to be a POD, just "standard layout", which is a lightly weaker condition. Quoth section 9.2 [class.mem] paragraph 20 of the standard:

> A pointer to a standard-layout struct object, suitably converted using a reinterpret_cast, points to its
>   initial member (or if that member is a bit-field, then to the unit in which it resides) and vice versa. [ Note:
>   There might therefore be unnamed padding within a standard-layout struct object, but not at its beginning,
>   as necessary to achieve appropriate alignment. — end note ]

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As for the 2nd example will it be of size 7?Even if the size is 8 (either by padding or if array_b is 6 bytes) will I access correctly all bytes serially or is there a possibility to be larger than 8 and have padding in between?

Comment: The size of your `test` struct will be at least 7 bytes, but it might well be more if the compiler has decided to put padding between the two members. Passing `sizeof(test)` and then stepping through 7 `char`s as you do in your example is not portable, and won't work if there is space between the two members. Having said that, most compilers have extensions to allow you to specify that a struct should  not be padded if you really really need to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is free to add padding and reorganize the struct how it sees fit. Especially in C++ you can add (virtual) functions and then chances are that the virtual table is hidden before that. But of course that are implementation details.
For C this assumption is valid.

Answer (score 0):

For C, it's largely implementation-specific, but in practice the rule (in the absence of #pragma pack or something likewise) is:

- Struct members are stored in the order they are declared. (This is required by the C99 standard, as mentioned here earlier.)
- If necessary, padding is added before each struct member, to ensure correct alignment.

So given a struct like

```
struct test{
char ch;
int i;
}
```

will have ch at offset 0, then a padding byte to align, i at offset 2 and then at the end, padding bytes are added to make the struct size a multiple of 8 bytes.(on a 64-bit machine,  4 byte alignment may be permitted in 32 bit machines)

So at least in this case, for C, I think you can assume that the struct pointer will point to the first array.