# Using Struct Members As Array, The Portable Way?

Tags: c++

I have the following struct (lets take this case with 1 type as a simple case):

```
struct Vector {
    double x_, y_, z_;
};
```

According to [C/C++ Pointer to a POD struct also points to the 1st struct member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19786013/c-c-pointer-to-a-pod-struct-also-points-to-the-1st-struct-member) it seems that, in general, given there is no padding, you can write something like this:

```
int main() 
{
    Vector v{ 32.0, 42.0, 68.0 };
    double* d = &v.x_;
    for( int i = 0; i < 3; ++i ){
        std::cout << d[ i ] << ", ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

And it should print out `32, 42, 68,` in most cases, however as a comment in response to the marked answer on this question remarks, the struct may have padding, and this may not be portable. What would happen if the `struct` were written like this however?

```
struct alignas( double ) Vector {
    double x_, y_, z_;
};
```

And I were to write a functor like this

```
//VectorComponent is an enum class, I will spare the reader the details.//
template< VectorComponent ComponentSelectorConstant >
struct GetComponent
{
    const double& ComponentConstant;
    GetComponent( const Vector& vector ) : 
            ComponentConstant( ( &vector.x_ )[ static_cast< size_t >( ComponentSelectorConstant ) ] ) {
    }
    operator const double&() {
        return ComponentConstant;
    }
};
```

Because now there is explicit alignment, to the type specified (`double`), does that mean that the following code is not undefined behavior, is portable, and has a guaranteed output according to the C++20 standard?

```
int main() {
    Vector v{ .x_ = 23, .y_ = 43, .z_ = 64 };
    std::cout << GetComponent< VectorComponent::Z >( v ) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Also since the the concept of POD's has changed, what about previous C++ standards (that included the idea of POD and `alignas`)?

Comment: Even if there is no padding and the elements are each exactly `sizeof(double)` away from each other, the rules of pointer arithmetic still do not allow you to reach one member from a pointer to another member.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux So the memory is not required to be contiguous?

Comment: The C++ standard offers you no guarantees, whatsoever. What is the real problem you're trying to solve. No, not the problem of accessing struct members as an array, but the problem to which the solution you believe involves accessing struct members as an array, so that's what you're asking about. Perhaps if you ask about the real problem, a simpler, cleaner solution is possible instead of this.

Comment: You **cannot** treat the members of a struct as an array.  For a portable work around, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62089026/4342498

Comment: Whether or not the memory is contiguous is irrelevant.  The compiler obeys the rules as laid out in the standard for the C++ abstract machine.  If your code violates the rules, it has undefined behavior.  The compiler trusts that your code does not violate the rules, and may make optimization assumptions that are incorrect for your invalid code, leading to undesirable behavior at the worst possible moment.  Either leading to hilarity and antics, or to late night debugging sessions on the day before shipping product.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux If you post that as an answer I will mark it as such

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Really just trying to get the assumptions (and potentially*  performance) that come with what use to be called POD's (I guess "Standard Layout Type" and "Trivial Types" now) and not add a `operator[]`.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you for providing the link.

Comment: One of the problems is that unintentional UB is so ubiquitous. And things usually work as expected which means it gets cleaned out from old code less often. Probably dates back to the early days of C and C++ but is more critical and likely to do the unexpected as complex optimization improved.

Comment: If you really want array indexing over the members, define an `operator[]` for that purpose, eg: `struct Vector { double x_, y_, z_;  double& operator[](size_t index) { switch (index) { case 0: return x_; case 1: return y_; case 2: return z_; default: throw std::out_of_range("invalid index"); } } };` Then you can use `Vector v{...}; v[index]` as needed.

Comment: @doug It seems to me the standard gets a little too specific at times

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you, for the moment I am trying to get the benefits of a POD like type, that might change though. Thanks again!

Comment: @TheFloatingBrain The `Vector` shown above is still a POD type even though it has an `operator[]` defined on it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think I was deferring looking a little deeper into it because I thought I heard otherwise that at some point, while I have been tacitly aware of this

Comment: @TheFloatingBrain I think lots of things shouldn't be UB that are. And there are some things that clearly are UB  in the standard library and are only defined behavior by fiat since they can't be coded without UB. For instance std::complex which requires arrays of complex objects to be accessible through this: `reinterpret_cast<T*>(p)[2*i + 1] `  But us mere mortals can't do this with our own structures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of the memory layout of your `struct`, pointer arithmetic forbids this strategy. The relevant rule in this case is ([link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_subscript_operator)) :

> The built-in subscript expression `E1[E2]` is exactly identical to the expression `*(E1 + E2)` [except evaluation order (since C++17)], that is, the pointer operand (which may be a result of array-to-pointer conversion, and **which must point to an element of some array or one past the end**) is adjusted to point to another element of the same array, following the rules of pointer arithmetics, and is then dereferenced.

The members of your `struct` are not part of an array so you may not derive a pointer to one of them from a pointer to another.

In some cases, the rules will allow you to get a pointer that is both non-dereferencable and also coincidentally holds the address of an actual object of the same type. This can occur with one-past-the-end pointers. But even in these cases you cannot use that pointer to access the object at that address. *How* you get a pointer matters. If you get it illegally you can break assumptions the compiler made leading to unexpected behavior. These are assumptions that the compiler would have been allowed to make based on the belief that your code would not break the rules of the language.

Answer (score 0):

> it seems that, in general, given there is no padding, you can write something like this:

It might seem so, but we cannot because the behaviour of the pointer arithmetic is undefined.

> What would happen if the struct were written like this however?
>
> ```
> struct alignas( double ) Vector
> ```

No difference. The class already had that alignment requirement, and the alignment has would have no effect on the validity of the pointer arithmetic anyway.

> And I were to write a functor like this

That functor still has UB for the same reason, so it is not useful.

---

> Using Struct Members As Array, The Portable Way?

The portable way is to use an array as an array:

```
struct Vector : std::array<double, 3> {};
```

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Gave a deeper reason why, so I marked his answer as correct, thank you though!